# Split words in java and also handle double quote

Tags: java, split

I have CSV file which I reading through the FileReader. readLine will give me the first line of the CSV file as String.

String str = 1,1,1,"12345",Name,"Cat,Dog";

Now comma (,) is my delimeter and if i split the String it is giving me the Output

1
1
12345
Name
"Cat
Dog"

But instead of this output I want that if some value will be there in ""(double quote);in that case it should take the full value (without splitting )

1
1
12345
Name
Cat,Dog

Comment: You might want to look for a standard CSV parser instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Can you please give me a idea who I do it by using CSV parser.I haven't use yet.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s = "Sachin,,M,\"Maths,Science,English\",Need to improve in these subjects.";
   String[] splitted = s.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
 }
```

Out put : [Sachin, , M, "Maths,Science,English", Need to improve in these subjects.]
For eg

splitted[0] = Sachin

splitted[1] =  (Empty String)

splitted[2] = M

splitted[3] = "Maths,Science,English"

splitted[4] = Need to improve in these subjects.

No need to check \ is present or not. We are using this regex to split csv .

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
String line = "1,1,1,\"12345\",Name,\"Cat,Dog\"";

    if (line.contains("\"")) {
        line = line.replaceAll("(\"\\,|\\,\")|\\,|\"$", " ");
        System.out.println(line);
    }else {
        // code to split the line
    }
```

Output : `1 1 1 12345 Name Cat Dog`